# Connect (synology) NAS with other server over VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, nas

Is there a way to connect a NAS (in my case a synology NAS) to another NAS or server in another network via VPN?

My idea/ goal would be that if you are in the local network of NAS 1 the drives of the remote server/ NAS 2 feel or look like they are on the local NAS and you don't have to connect to a VPN every time you start your computer and just connect to the (local) NAS that would then connect to the remote server.

This is probably an edge case but I would be interested if this is possible somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about this, because everything that comes up is how to connect a computer via VPN to a NAS

Comment: That might be because this is usually done with an ordinary site-to-site VPN, i.e. letting the routers make the other NAS directly reachable, without getting the local NAS involved in any "NAS-to-NAS" stuff.

Comment: That depends on your internet connection speed and latency. If it is worse then your LAN speed/latency the remote files might look but will not feel like local files. Unless you use some kind of sync between the NASs so that the files are replicated as local files (similar to a local cash of a network drive).

Comment: I know that they wont feel like local. I just want them appear on the NAS, so everybody in the network can access them without setting up a vpn on every computer.